# Why there is one more '/' after Nginx rewrite?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In the `nginx.conf` of website.com I put this:

`rewrite ^test/(.+)$ http://www.websitenew.com/test/$1 permanent;`

Then when I use `curl -I www.website.com/test/en` I got this in the redirection header:

`Location: http://www.websitenew.com//test/en`

I can see that `website.com` had successfully rewritten to `websitenew.com` and the URL scheme is also correct, but why there is one more `/` between `websitenew.com` and `/test`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rewrite ^test/(.+)$ http://www.websitenew.com/test/$1 permanent;

This rule can't work actually, and your redirect is made by something else. There's no URI in nginx that not start with `/`, but your rule doesn't have `/` at the beginning.